# Conditions for convergence and the multivariate central limit theorem

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

Consider $r$ independent but not identically distributed random vectors $x_1,\dots,x_r$, each of dimension $d$. The elements of $x_i$ are integer valued elements in the range $-d,\dots,d$ with mean $0$ and variance $d$. Each element of each vector $x_i$ is in fact just distributed as a simple symmetric random walk with $d$ steps. The elements of $x_i$ may not however be independent.

> Under what conditions does $\sum_{j=1}^r x_i$ (suitably scaled) converge to a
>   multivariate Gaussian as $r$ and $d$ go to infinity?

Is there some relationship between $d$ and $r$ that is necessary for convergence?

Comment: The elements of $x_i$ are also independent?

Comment: @leonbloy Just added that this second. No, they may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition, given that $x_i$ are bounded, is that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n C_i \to C$, where $C_i$ are the covariance matrices. Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}( \sum x_i - \mu_i)\to N(0,C)$. See eg [here](http://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/Bunzel/documents/Asymptoticspart5.pdf).

Comment: If $d=2^r$, say, doesn't that affect convergence?  It feels like the relationship between r and d should be relevant.

Comment: @Lembik Yes, the above assumes $d$ is fixed.

Comment: Oh! What happens when $d$ is not fixed?

Comment: The link is broken now. Is there another link you can provide?

Comment: I’m looking for exactly this for research and a reference would be fantastic.